# Argument principle for essential singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f : B_0(r) \setminus \{0\} \to \Bbb C$ be holomorphic, where $B_0(r) \setminus \{0\}$ is the punctured disc of radius $r$.

Assume that $f$ has an essential singularity at $0$.

Is there any way to find $\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac {f'} f, 0\right)$ from the Laurent series of $f$ at $0$?

Comment: How can $f$ have an essential singularity at $0$ if it is meromorphic in a disc containing $0$? Meromorphic means the only singularities are poles. Essential singularities are not poles.

Comment: @MPW sorry, edited

Comment: When you are asking for $\text{Res}\Big(\frac{f'}{f},0\Big)$, you are assuming that $\frac{f'}{f}$ has a singularity at $0$. But how do you check that? Great Picard's theorem states that a holomorphic function around essential singularities hits each value infinitely many times with at most one exception. But here that exception has to be zero. If it is not, then $f$ would have infinitely many zeros around $0$, so $\frac{f'}{f}$ would have infinitely many poles around $0$ which means that it isn't holomorphic in punctured neghbourhood of $0$, meaning that $0$ is not a singularity.

Comment: Interesting viewpoint. Obviously this was 3 years ago so I don't remember what I was thinking. But do you think that this question cannot be salvaged from being nonsense?